# In C# How to correctly pass an int array to a function

Tags: c#, arrays

how do I pass an array with an unknown number of integers to a function?
Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

I get the following error when trying to run the code:

Error   CS1501  No overload for method 'Solution' takes 6 arguments

```
using System;

namespace IntegerTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int Solution(int[] input)
        {
            Array.Sort(input);

            int index = 0;

            // Skip negatives
            while (index < input.Length && input[index] < 1)
                index++;

            int expected = 1;
            while (index < input.Length)
            {
                if (input[index] > expected)
                    return expected;

                // Skip number and all duplicates
                while (index < input.Length && input[index] == expected)
                    index++;

                expected++;
            }

            return expected;
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Solution( 1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2));

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/

Comment: You need the `params` keyword before the array to accept vararg style input; otherwise, pass in an int array, your just passing in a bunch of independent ints right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method accepts a `int[]`, so create a `new int[]`

```
Solution(new int[] {1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either call the function with an array argument (e.g. `Solution(new[] {1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2})`, or modify the function signature to take a `params` argument (`int Solution(params int[] input)`).

Answer (score 0):

You are passing 6 arguments to a method that takes one. Change your main method to something like this:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] arr = { 1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2};
        Console.WriteLine(Solution(arr));

    }
```